# Extract first number in a sequence of identical numbers in a pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to group a dataframe by a column 'type', and get the first number from each sequence of identical numbers. The following example illustrates:

```
A = pd.DataFrame({'type':['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B'], 'value':[1,1,1,1,8,8,8,1,1,2,2,3,3,2]})
```

For group A, there is first a sequence of 1's, then of 8's, and a final of 1's. For group B, there is first one of 2's, then one of 3's, and a last one of 2's (only one element). The result should be 1,8,1 for A and 2,3,2 for B:

```
type  value
0    A      1
1    A      8
2    A      1
3    B      2
4    B      3
5    B      2
```

Note that using A.groupby('type').first(), nor A.groupby('type').(lambda x:x.unique()) will work because in both cases the last 1 and the last 2 would be ignored. Note that this would be trivial if I had an index to identify each series of same numbers.

Thank you and I appreciate all your help,

Comment: Is the DataFrame sorted by type?

Comment: Thank you ayhan. it is sorted by type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def first_contiguous(s):
    return s.groupby(s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()).head(1)

A.groupby('type').value.apply(first_contiguous).reset_index('type')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you piRSquared, this seems to be working really well! I have a few additional questions : 1) the result from s.ne(shift() ) is either TRUE or FALSE depending on whether or not the *following* value equals the current value. How does cumsum() add these true's and false's to come up with the number? 2) In my case, I dont get the name of the column value, instead I get zero. what would be a good way to resolve this? thank you for all yor help

Comment: @dleal technically, I'm testing if current is equal to the prior.  Each `True` signifies the beginning of a new series of equal numbers.  `cumsum` on `bool` values treats the `True`/`False` as `1`/`0`.  So the first `True` gets a `1`.  Each subsequent `False` adds `0` which keeps the `cumsum` at `1` untill the next `True` at which time `cumsum` increments to `2` which is perfect because that is the beginning of the next series of equal values.  I then use this to `groupby`.

Comment: @dleal I don't understand your second question.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation piRSquared, very clever idea. I think I figured out the second question.